# How to use javascript packages which don't support typescript in React.js Typescript version

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm developing the admin dashboard and researched the right chart library for the design.

It was [react-timeseries-charts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-timeseries-charts) library. But the problem is that doesn't support the Typescript version like `type@react-timeseries-charts` such as other popular libraries.

My React.js project uses `Typescript` and can't change it to Javascript due to just this chart library.

I know many libraries don't support the `Typescript` version now and want to make sure how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add custom type definition of that module. [This](https://www.detroitlabs.com/blog/2018/02/28/adding-custom-type-definitions-to-a-third-party-library/) and [this](http://blog.wolksoftware.com/contributing-to-definitelytyped) articles describes how to do it.